# How to pass the props from parent to child to child of child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to pass the props from App.js(parent) to CommentItem.js(child) to Button.js(child of child),
but the props is empty in Button,js(child of child)'s component.

1. App.js(parent) to CommentItem.js(child)

I pushed `mainuser: this.state.head` to FlatList, and the props(mainuser) passed by `renderItem={({ item }) => <CommentItem {...item}`

And, CommentItem.js(child) received `mainuser` by the code below.

```
const {
    head,
    text,
    created,
    mainuser,
    subuser,
  } =
```

2. CommentItem.js(child) to Button.js(child of child)

I thought props was pased to Button by ,
and Button(child of child) received the props by the code below.

```
const {
      mainuser,
    } = this.props;
```

However, props id empty in Button.js(child of child).

#
Are there any problems of my code?
Could you give some advice please?

---

App.js(parent)

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      head: [],
      list: [],
    };
  }

  _onPress = (text) => {
    const list = [].concat(this.state.list);

   list.push({
      key: Date.now(),
      text: text,
      done: false,
      mainuser: this.state.head,
    });

    this.setState({
      list,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      head,
      list,
    } = this.state;

    var data = [["User1", "User2", "User3"],];

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.dropdownHeader}>
        <View style={styles.dropdown}>
          <DropdownMenu
            style={{flex: 1}}
            bgColor={'white'}
            tintColor={'#666666'}
            activityTintColor={'green'}
            handler={(selection, row) => this.setState({head: data[selection][row]})}
            data={data}
          >
          </DropdownMenu>
        </View>
        </View>
      <Text>To Do</Text>
            <View style={styles.postinput}>
              <CommentInput onPress={this._onPress} />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.CommentListContainer}>
            <FlatList
              /*inverted*/
              style={styles.CommentList}
              data={list}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <CommentItem {...item} /> }
            />
          </View>
    );
  }
}
```

CommentItem.js(child)

```
const CommentItem = (props) => {
  const {
    head,
    text,
    created,
    mainuser,
    subuser,
  } = props;


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.left}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.function}>
        <Button {...mainuser} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Button.js(child of child)

```
export default class ApplauseButton extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    const {
      mainuser,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{mainuser}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `mainuser` is an object or array?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. mainuser is object.

Comment: if you're deeply passing state as props and you find state management being cumbersome look into a library (redux, mobx, etc.) or look at react context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your code it seems that main user is array,

```
this.state = {
  head: [],//array
  list: [],
};

....
list.push({
      key: Date.now(),
      text: text,
      done: false,
      mainuser: this.state.head,// main user should be array
});
```

so you need to give prop name also in `<Button />`

like this

`<Button mainuser={mainuser} />`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access `mainuser` as a prop, then you've to pass it as `<Button mainuser={mainuser} />`.

As it stands, you're [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)ing the contents of `mainuser`.